# java : Is it a bad practice to store file streams in a database?

Tags: java, jpa, filestreams

I'm reading a file streams of certain group of files and storing it in a database as `bytea` type. But when I try to read the streams from the database and write those streams into a file, It is really taking long to do it and finally I get an out of memory exception. Is there any other alternative where it can be done more efficiently with or without database involved?

Comment: Generally speaking, a database is not for storing files, a _filesystem_ is. So store the files on the filesystem and _point_ to them from the database - i.e. store the path to the files in the DB.

Comment: "get an out of memory exception": it is not necessary to keep the whole file in memory at once. Read and write it piece by piece.

Comment: Thank you both for the response, @Henry You mean to say read file by file from the database and not altogether?

Comment: Share your code. There's nothing intrinsically wrong with putting binary data in the database, but as Boris the Spider remarked, it may make more sense to store them in a filesystem. An `OutOfMemroryError` should not occur from simply reading and writing a byte stream, though, unless you decide to read everything into main memory.

Comment: Agree with answer from @Edwin Buck ... but new times give controversial soluitions, cloud multinode database naturally provide new virtual file system etc.... (Hadoop and family). Sometimes strange decision can be accepted. My comment is strictrly at theoretical level, I don't speak about details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Databases were designed with a key problem in mind:

```
When having a bunch of data, where we don't know the kinds of reports
that will be generated, how can we store the data in a manner that
preserves the data's inner relationships and permits any reporting
format we can think of. a
```

Files lack a few key characteristics of databases.  Files consistently have a single structure of "characters in order".  They also lack any means of integrated report building, and the reporting is often confined to simple searches, which have little context without the result being shown in the rest of the file.

In short, if you aren't using the database's features, please don't use the database.

Many people do store files in databases; because, they have one handy, and instead of writing support for a filesystem storage, they cut-and-paste the database storage code.  Let's explore the consequences:

1. Backups and restores become problematic because the database grows in size very quickly, and the bandwidth to do the backup and restore is a function of the size of the database.
2. Replication rebuilds in fail-safe databases take longer (I've seen some go so long that redundancy couldn't catch up to the rate of change in the primary database).
3. Queries that (accidentally) reference the files in bulk spike the CPU, possibly starving access to the rest of the system (depends on database).
4. Bandwidth of returning the results of those queries steals system resources preventing other queries from communicating their results (better on some databases, worse on others).

Comment: Agree and vote Up, but new cloud solutions give deterrent look f/e backup question. Backup does n exist, replications is 'new backup' (tell is short, I understant difference). For everage single programmer: agree with answer